# Replaces lines in buffer with each line wrapped in a block of text?

Tags: emacs, elisp

There is a buffer with the following contents.

```
foo
bar baz bat
more text
Lorem Ipsum fido
```

The goal is to turn this listing into a HTML table with the following block wrapping each line of the buffer.

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
??Text Here??
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
8</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
&#160;</td>
</tr>
```

With `??Text Here` replaced with a line from the buffer.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yasnippet has built-in support for wrap-around of selected text.  Perhaps a `(save-excursion (goto-char (point-max)) (while (re-search-backward "\n" nil t) . . .))` could be built-in to the snippet -- if not, then a separate `elisp` function could call the snippet where I have `. . .` listed above.  Of course, it can be done without yasnippet also.

Comment: I was hoping for something that was easy to use "on the fly". This kind of thing pops up now and then but I rarely need to do the same transform again some other day. So the over head of making a snippet just to replace 50 odd lines is a bit much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines are not too long the following works (note the `\&`-tick that expands to the full match as it is described in the help of `query-replace-regexp`):

1. Set the cursor to the beginning of the first line.
2. Press <kbd>M-:</kbd>
3. Paste the following text into the minibuffer and press <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```lisp
(query-replace-regexp "^.*$" "<tr>
<td style=\"text-align: center;\">
\\&
</td>
<td style=\"text-align: center;\">
8</td>
<td style=\"text-align: center;\">
&#160;</td>
</tr>")
```

4. Press <kbd>! to replace all lines.</kbd>

---

Alternatively you can also:

1. Set the cursor to the beginning of the first line.
2. Press <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> to interactively invoke `query-replace-regexp`
3. Paste the source regexp `^.*$` into the minibuffer and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. following into the minibuffer:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
\&
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
8</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
&#160;</td>
</tr>
```

and press <kbd>enter</kbd> and  !  to replace all matches.

Comment: I added a comment on `\&`. Sorry, for any inconvenience caused by the missing comment.